# How can I maintain stacking divs on center meanwhile the second div take full remaining width

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve like this. I drew two page on the picture. The left one is for small screen. The right one is for larger screen. My goal here is to stack two divs in the center with one overlapping the other meanwhile the second div's width takes the remaining document width but the text box inside the second div maintains the same margin as the first div.

Update: I would like to maintain the same margin for both section 1 and section 2 contents.

[image]

Comment: Could you please illustrate what you want your final result to be? I couldn't seem to imagine it

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understood from your image. When you will apply it to your complete code it might not display exact behaviour but achieves what is shown in the image. To make it work with your code you have to modify it a little bit as I don't have your code.
Here is the link to code pen https://codepen.io/rk-v/pen/QWvVWBa

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="right">Left</div>
  <div class="left">
    <div>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;  /* grow */
  border: 1px dashed #f0f;
  margin: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 15rem;
  height: 5rem;
}
.left p{
  margin-left: 3rem;
} 

.right {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dashed #00f;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 2rem;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 15rem;
}
```

Comment: It's close with what i wanted. I want to stack the left and right div too.

Comment: You have solved it or should I edit the answer for you??

Comment: Thanks, I updated the pic for more detail. I would like to maintain the same margin for both section 1 and 2 content. The dark yellow div that wrapping the yellow div should take the remaining width. In section 1, blue and dark yellow divs should remain stacking regard of the screen size and the yellow inner div should maintain the margin.

Comment: @uranium235
I have updated the code. But to work, you have to modify length values based on your complete code